# Parallax scrolling is stuttering in Internet Explorer 11 and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, parallax

I have a solution for a parallax like scrolling effect for a website but somehow it behaves shaky in Safari 9.0.1 (Mac) and Internet Explorer 11 (Windows 7).

My solution uses jQuery 1.11 and works by adjusting the `background-position` of a div with jQuery's `.css()` method. This should have the visual effect of a fixed background image which can be scrolled over.

Here is a simplified demo of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lypnb63c/1/

To be more precise the problem seems to relate with the function `dontScrollBackground()`.

One strange thing that I have discovered is also that most browsers get more shaky once I remove a div with `position:fixed`.

Here a demo with a div element with `position:fixed`: https://jsfiddle.net/Lypnb63c/1/

**Question:**

1. Does anyone have a clue if there is a browser specific problem with my solution?
2. Is there a simple way to make it work in all major browsers?

One solution could be the usage of pure css but I would like to try it with my current solution first.

I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem myself. The problem was line 12 `$(this).css("background-position", "52% " + (st - y) + "px");`.

I found out that the same effect can be reached by adding the following style to the element representing the background: `background-attachment: fixed`. Therefore the solution of my problem was to change the above mentioned line 12 to `$(this).css("background-attachment", "fixed");`

I hope my solution will help people who run into a similar problem like I did.